# Finding the Taylor series of $\int_{0}^{z}e^{\xi^{2}}d\xi$ about $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

As suggested by the title, i want to find the Taylor series of $\int_{0}^{z}e^{\xi^{2}}d\xi$ about $z=0$.

Although it seems like a typical "finding the Taylor series of $f(z)$" type of question, i can't seem to obtain the function which is to be expanded. I know that $f(\xi)=e^{\xi^{2}}$ is an entire function on $\mathbb{C}$, so by the fundamental theorem of calculus, its anti-derivative must exist.

As such, i am thinking that i should evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{z}e^{\xi^{2}}d\xi$ first but it seems like the closed form of $f(z)$ is going to be very complicated. What should i do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: integrate the Taylor series of $e^{\xi^2}$ term by term.

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for the hint. Since the taylor series for $e^{z}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{n!}$, I will replace $z$ by $\xi^{2}$ to obtain $e^{\xi^{2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\xi^{2n}}{n!}=\frac{\xi^{2}}{1!}+\frac{\xi^{2.2}}{2!}+\frac{\xi^{2.3}}{3!}+...$. Thereafter, following your hint, i should integrate $\frac{\xi^{2}}{1!}+\frac{\xi^{2.2}}{2!}+\frac{\xi^{2.3}}{3!}+...$ term-wise. Is that correct?

Comment: @Cleytus, yes exactly!

Answer (score 0):

The function $e^{\xi^2}$ has no elementary [anti-derivative.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)

Let $f(\xi)=e^{\xi^2}$ so $$\int_{0}^z f(\xi)d\xi=F(\xi)|_{0}^z=F(z)-F(0)$$

To construct a taylor series for your function, you need the value of the function at $0$ as well as the values of its derivatives. In this case, the function evaluated at $0$ would be $F(0)-F(0)=0$.

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $$\frac{d}{dz}(F(z)-F(0))=f(z)$$
You can now use the MacLaurin Series for the exponential function to construct the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2n}}{n!} $$